# Insert $_POST into HTML form action

Tags: php, html

I want to insert `$_POST` value into the HTML form action. By using my code I got this error message: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) ...**.

This is my sample code in my `PHP` file:

```
print <<< HERE
<form action="../../path/to/file.php?id=<?php echo $_POST['mytext'];?>" method="POST">
    // some stuff here ...
    <input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
HERE;
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why??? you can assign `$_GET['id']` with `$_POST['mytext']` after form submission too. `$_POST['mytext']` would be undefined index untill your form is submitted

Comment: Don't understand, Can you show me a sample code?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `id` in the form action

```
<form action="../../path/to/file.php" method="POST">
// some stuff here ...
<input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Instead in the `file.php` you can make a variable and assign `$_POST['mytext']` to that variable

```
$id = $_POST['mytext'];
```

Comment: That's the good solution! Thank you! Answer is accepted! BTW, can you show me how should be the proper syntax, why I got that error?

Comment: I think you have missed some quote over there. BTW I have tested this code and it works fine on my side. But you can't get the `$_POST['mytext']` value until you submit the form

Comment: I think the problem with the syntax can be the using of **print <<< HERE** and **HERE;**

Comment: Hmm.. you might be right. I just copy pasted the `form` tag inside my editor